# Doxygen: How to use \fn command to document class member functions in C?

Tags: doxygen

I document classes in C by using `\class` and `\memberof` doxygen commands. For example, here is a header file `foo.h`:

```
/*! \file
* \brief Foo header
*/

/*! \class Foo */
typedef struct {
    uint8_t x; /*!< this is x member */
} Foo;

/*! \memberof Foo */
uint32_t Foo_oper(Foo * const me, uint16_t z);
```

This all works fine. But my code is safety-related and therefore it needs to change as infrequently as possible. For that reason, I want to place the detailed documentation in a separate file, say `api.dox` (which can change more frequently than the code):

```
/*! \page api API Reference
* \brief API reference
*/

/*! \class Foo
* \details Sample class Foo documentation added externally.
*/

/*! \var Foo::x
* \details Sample Foo::x documentation added externally.
*/

/*! \fn Foo::Foo_oper(Foo * const me, uint16_t z)
* \details Sample Foo::Foo_oper() documentation added externally.
*/
```

This works for the class `Foo` and data member `Foo::x`, but does not add the external documentation to the member function `Foo::Foo_oper()`. (It works when I remove the `\memberof Foo` command from the declaration of `Foo_oper()`).

Instead, doxygen (version 1.9.7) reports a warning:

```
api.dox:14: warning: documented symbol 'Foo::Foo_oper' was not declared or defined.
```

I already tried to reference the function `Foo::Foo_oper()` with and without the whole signature. Please note that doxygen generates correctly the following link `\ref Foo::Foo_oper()`.

How do I make it work? How to reference the "member function" `Foo::Foo_oper()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly but it seems you indeed do not have a declaration for `Foo::Foo_oper()` in your header, just a top-level function `Foo_oper()` outside of the struct. This function takes a Foo pointer as argument but it is not a member of Foo itself, right?

Comment: It this intended to be C or C++? Why do you use the `\memberof`?

Comment: This *is* intended for C, where I emulate classes, as shown in the foo.h header file. Doxygen anticipates such emulated association between struct and functions and precisely for that purpose it provides the \class and \memberof special commands. The problem is how to add external documentation. Again, Doxygen provides \fn command for it, but it seems to break down for functions with the \memberof comment. I hope this clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work. It turns out that the external documentation file(s) must be the last in the **order** of Doxygen input files. For the simple example described in the original post, the Doxygen `INPUT` needs to be defined as follows:

```
INPUT = foo.h \
        foo.c \
        foo.dox
```